# keras custom metric function how to feed 2 model outputs to a single metric evaluation function

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow, keras, deep-learning

I have an CNN object detection model which has two heads(outputs) with tensor names `'classification'` and `'regression'`.

I want to define a metric function that **accepts both the outputs at the same time**, so that it looks into the **regression predictions** to decide which indexes to retain and use those indexes to select tensors from **classification predictions** and calculate some metric.

my current metric function defined with help from [this link](https://www.tensorflow.org/beta/guide/keras/training_and_evaluation#passing_data_to_multi-input_multi-output_models):

```
from tensorflow.python.keras.metrics import MeanMetricWrapper

class Accuracy2(MeanMetricWrapper):

    def __init__(self, name='dummyAccuracy', dtype=None):
        super(Accuracy2, self).__init__(metric_calculator_func, name, dtype=dtype)
        self.true_positives = self.add_weight(name='lol', initializer='zeros')

    @classmethod
    def from_config(cls, config):
        if 'fn' in config:
          config.pop('fn')
        return super(Accuracy2, cls).from_config(config)


    def update_state(self, y_true, y_pred, sample_weight=None):
      print("==@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@===")
      print("Y-True {}".format(y_true))
      print("Y-Pred {}".format(y_pred))
      print("==@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@===")

      update_ops = [self.true_positives.assign_add(1.0)]
      return tf.group(update_ops)

    def result(self):
      return self.true_positives

    def reset_states(self):
      # The state of the metric will be reset at the start of each epoch.
      self.true_positives.assign(0.)
```

which I call the during model compilation as :

```
training_model.compile(
    loss={
        'regression'    : regression_loss(),
        'classification': classification_loss()
    },
    optimizer=keras.optimizers.Adam(lr=lr, clipnorm=0.001),
    metrics=[Accuracy2()]
)
```

screen log during **tf.estimator.train_and_evaluate** is:

> INFO:tensorflow:loss = 0.0075738616, step = 31 (11.941 sec)
>
> INFO:tensorflow:global_step/sec: 4.51218
>
> INFO:tensorflow:loss = 0.01015341, step = 36 (1.108 sec)
>
> INFO:tensorflow:Saving checkpoints for 40 into /tmp/tmpcla2n3gy/model.ckpt.
>
> INFO:tensorflow:Calling model_fn.
>   ==@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@===
>   Tensor("IteratorGetNext:1", shape=(?, 120087, 5), dtype=float32, device=/device:CPU:0)
>   Tensor("regression/concat:0", shape=(?, ?, 4), dtype=float32)
>   ==@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@===
>   ==@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@===
>   Tensor("IteratorGetNext:2", shape=(?, 120087, 2), dtype=float32, device=/device:CPU:0)
>   Tensor("classification/concat:0", shape=(?, ?, 1), dtype=float32)
>   ==@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@===
>
> INFO:tensorflow:Done calling model_fn.
>
> INFO:tensorflow:Starting evaluation at 2019-06-24T08:20:35Z
>   INFO:tensorflow:Graph was finalized.
>   2019-06-24 13:50:36.457345: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1512] Adding visible gpu devices: 0
>   2019-06-24 13:50:36.457398: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:984] Device interconnect StreamExecutor with strength 1 edge matrix:
>   2019-06-24 13:50:36.457419: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:990]      0 
>   2019-06-24 13:50:36.457425: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1003] 0:   N 
>   2019-06-24 13:50:36.457539: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1115] Created TensorFlow device (/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:GPU:0 with 9855 MB memory) -> physical GPU (device: 0, name: GeForce RTX 2080 Ti, pci bus id: 0000:01:00.0, compute capability: 7.5)
>
> INFO:tensorflow:Restoring parameters from /tmp/tmpcla2n3gy/model.ckpt-40
>
> INFO:tensorflow:Running local_init_op.
>
> INFO:tensorflow:Done running local_init_op.
>
> INFO:tensorflow:Evaluation [10/100]
>
> INFO:tensorflow:Evaluation [20/100]
>
> INFO:tensorflow:Evaluation [30/100]
>
> INFO:tensorflow:Evaluation [40/100]
>
> INFO:tensorflow:Evaluation [50/100]
>
> INFO:tensorflow:Evaluation [60/100]
>
> INFO:tensorflow:Evaluation [70/100]
>
> INFO:tensorflow:Evaluation [80/100]
>
> INFO:tensorflow:Evaluation [90/100]
>
> INFO:tensorflow:Evaluation [100/100]
>
> INFO:tensorflow:Finished evaluation at 2019-06-24-08:20:44
>
> INFO:tensorflow:Saving dict for global step 40: _focal = 0.0016880237, _smooth_l1 = 0.0, dummyAccuracy = 100.0, global_step = 40, loss = 0.0016880237

This line :

```
==@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@===
Tensor("IteratorGetNext:1", shape=(?, 120087, 5), dtype=float32, device=/device:CPU:0)
Tensor("regression/concat:0", shape=(?, ?, 4), dtype=float32)
==@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@===
==@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@===
Tensor("IteratorGetNext:2", shape=(?, 120087, 2), dtype=float32, device=/device:CPU:0)
Tensor("classification/concat:0", shape=(?, ?, 1), dtype=float32)
==@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@===
```

shows that `Accuracy2()` is invoked two times first for **regression** then for **classification**.
but I want that it gets invoked once with **regression** and **classification** fed into it together

Comment: Any comments about my solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### If you need both `y_true` values for the metric.

In this case we will need to flatten our data so we can concat it in a single array.
This will need fixed size outputs.

Assuming you have `regOut` and `classOut` as tensors. If they are 2D, just concatenate them, else:

```
regOut = Flatten()(regOut) #only if regOut is 3D or more
classOut = Flatten()(classOut) #only if classOut is 3D or more

out = Concatenate()([regOut,classOut])
```

Make the model with this single output:

```
model = Model(inputs, out)
```

Do the same with your datasets:

```
y_reg_train = y_reg_train.reshape((y_reg_train.shape[0], -1))
y_class_train = y_clas_trains.reshape((y_class_train.shape[0], -1))
y_train = np.concatenate([y_reg_train, y_class_train], axis=-1)

#same for y_val
```

Then create a metric that separates the two:

```
def metric(y_true, y_pred):

    reg_true = y_true[:,:flattened_size_of_reg]
    class_true = y_true[:, flattened_size_of_reg:]
    
    reg_pred = y_pred[:,:flattened_size_of_reg]
    class_pred = y_pred[:, flattened_size_of_reg:]

    #calculate the metric

    return value
```

Train with the combined output:

```
model.fit(x_train, y_train, ...)
```

Comment: awesome !! concatenating would totally work, I would only have to write a loss function which separates `regression` and `classification` head and feed them to their respective losses

Answer (score 1):

### If you don't need `y_true` values in that metric

This is an ugly answer, but....

You have to make a layer to calculate the metric for you. Use a `Lambda`:

Given that `regOut` and `classOut` are your output tensors, in model creation, instead of creating a model like `Model(inputs, [regOut,classOut])` you will:

```
def metricFunc(modelOutputs):
    regressionOutput = modelOutputs[0]
    classOutput = modelOuptuts[1]

    #calculate metric
    return calculatedMetric


metricTensor = Lambda(metricFunc, name='metric_layer')([regOut,classOut])
```

Make the metric be an output to the model:

```
model = Model(inputs, [regOut, classOut, metricTensor])
```

Create a dummy loss and a dummy metric for compilation:

```
def dummyLoss(true,pred):
    return K.zeros(K.shape(true)[:1])

def dummyMetric(true,pred):
    return pred
```

In compilation:

```
model.compile(loss = [regLoss, classLoss, dummyLoss], 
              metrics={'metric_layer':dummyMetric}, 
              optimizer=...)
```

This requires that you train with a dummy tensor for `metricTensor` too:

```
model.fit(x_train, [y_reg,y_class,np.zeros(y_reg.shape[:1])], ...)
```

Comment: Cool !!! the `metricFunc` function seems to be a good idea, I could use this to calculate the required indexes and filter the `classification`. then return this as a tensor named `metric_layer` which should be compiled with **dummyMetric**. Will try this.

Comment: Will wait to see If someone has a better solution. Otherwise gonna accept this.

Answer (score 0):

Let me show you an elegant way to achieve this.

- First of all, define an outer function that wraps your metric, so that you can pass your regression tensor `reg_out`:

  ```
  def metric_func(reg_out):
      def metric(y_true, class_out):
          return your_metric(reg_out, class_out, y_true)
      return metric
  ```
- Next, name your classification tensor `class_out` by setting the argument `name` of the layer that produces it. For example:

  ```
  class_out = Dense(1, name='class_out')(something)
  ```
- Finally, set the argument `metrics` of [model.compile](https://keras.io/models/model/#compile) as follows:

  ```
  model.compile(...,
                metrics={'class_out': metric_func(reg_out)})
  ```

Comment: This sounds cool :) - It seems it will work unless both `y_true` values are necessary for the metric.

Comment: Exactly. I understand from the OP that only the classification labels are required to compute the metric

Comment: @rvinas, `classification` labels are required for metric calculation, but `regression` results are required to select valid indexes(something like select indices whose IoU is greater than boxes)